# Best practice for DRYing up code in Rails action mailer previews?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I've got a series of related action mailer preview methods. In every method, I find myself copy and pasting the first five lines of code or so in order to create objects that are needed every time, e.g. an account and user.

I can abstract/DRY up stuff like this using a before block or a let statement in RSpec, or a before_action in a controller. What is the best practice for action mailer previews?

Comment: before_filter is good approach

Comment: before_filter doesn't work in action mailer previews

Comment: so then just call the method in each mailer_method. thats just 1 line of code. no problem

Answer (score -1):

Define an `initialize` function and put all repeating code in there. Remember to call `super` at the beginning of the function.